# Android studio not showing paired device via wifi or genymotion device in device selection list

Tags: android-studio

I have paired device with wifi and I can see device name in device manager of android studio

but device is not showing in devices list to run my app.

I have also this problem with geymotion devices,

I have genymotion 3.3.3
genymotion devices can get started but they not appear in device selection part.
[image]

I have also tried using this command (192.168.110.101 is genymotion device ip):

```
 .\adb connect 192.168.110.101:5555
```

and this is result:

```
already connected to 192.168.110.101:5555
```

but it's not working.
How can I run my app in a device?

Comment: Does it building correctly on the browser?

Comment: Have you restarted your machine? OR end the process of AVD?

Comment: Yes I've restarted them. I added tools and platform-tools path to `env` and it solved:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally problem solved by adding `tools` and `platform-tools` location to `path` of the environment variables.

Then I did a windows restart.